# How to get webpack mode value set by flag?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using `image-webpack-loader` to optimize images. I want to disable it via `options.disable = true` when my webpack mode is `development`. Now i'm trying to get mode from `process.env.NODE_ENV` but it's not working.

Here is a part of my webpack config:

```
const config = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'script.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}


module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
    config.mode = 'development';
  } else {
    config.mode = 'production';
  }

  return config;
};
```

I run my conifg via `webpack --mode=production` and `webpack --mode= development`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as webpack only sets `NODE_ENV` during the build. If you want this to be set when the config is loaded, you need to set it when launching the build in the command line. But, the best option for you is to turn the config into a function

```
const config = mode => ({
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'script.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              disable: mode === 'development',
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: mode === 'development' ? 'source-map' : undefined,
  mode
})


module.exports = (env, argv) => config(argv.mode)
```